# Using DTOs - Guidance

Tags: wcf, silverlight, dto

Looking for some guidance.

I'm building an application, SL4 with WCF as the backend service. My WCF Service layer sits over a Domain Model and I'm converting my Domain Entities to screen specific DTOs using an assembler.

I have a screen (security related) which shows a User and the Groups that they are a member of, now the user can add and remove groups for the user after which they can hit the apply button. Only when this apply button is hit will the changes be submitted.

Currently I have a UserDetailDto which is sent to the client to populate the screen and my intention was on hitting apply to send a UserDetailUpdateDto back to the server to perform the actual update to the domain model.

Does this sound ok to start?

If so when the user is making changes client-side should my UserDetailUpdateDto be sending back the changes, ie. whats been added and whats been removed.

Not sure, guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Guidance is always to tricky when so much is unknown about the requirements and the deployment environment. However, your approachs sounds reasonable to me. The key things I like about this:

1) You are keeping your DTOs separate from your Domain Entities. In small simple apps it can be fine to send entities over the wire, but they can start to get in each other's way as complexity and function increase.

2) You are differentiating between Query object (UserDetailDto) and Command object (UserDetailUpdateDto). Again the two can often be satisfied using a single object but you will start to them bloat as complexity/function increases because the object is serving two masters (the Query object is to be consumed at the client and the Command object is to be consumed at the server). I use a convention where all command DTOs start with a verb (e.g. UpdateUserDetail), it just makes it easier to sort 'data' from 'methods' at the client end.

If the SL application is likely to become large with more complex screen logic it may be worth looking at the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern. It allows you to separate screen design from screen function. It provides a bit more flexibility in distributing work around a development team and better supports unit testing.

As far as what gets sent back in the UpdateUserDetail object, I think this should be guided by what is going to be easiest to work with at the domain model (or the WCF service sitting over your domain model). Generally, smaller is better when it comes to DTOs.